# Check if a specific datetime is in between two fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm working on a calendar to book appointments.
I have rendered a calendar in table cells that looks like this:

[image]

Each cell has a timestamp and, for each cell, I'm trying to run a query to check if that particular timestamp exists in my reservations table:

[image]

`start` and `stop` is set to `datetime`.

It might be late, but I've come to the conclusion that this is the opposite of

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservations 
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2015-08-05 10:00:00' AND '2015-08-05 10:45:00')
```

...since in my case, I only have one specific time to check if is in between two different fields in the same record.

I tried `WHERE start >= ? AND stop <= ?` with the same date, but of course that didn't work since the stop date will never be the same as start date...

The result you see in the picture above is where I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

For each cell I run this query: `SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE day_time = ?` where the `?` is the timestamp in that particular cell.

It does work, but it seems to be a horrible way of accomplishing what I have.
Also, the time interval will not always be 15 minutes. It might be 5, 10, 30, or 1 hour. So to cover that change I would have to have a record for every 5 minutes an appointment is set to last..

What would be a good way to do this?

I've looked into different scripts ([Easy!Appointments](http://easyappointments.org/), [Booked](http://www.bookedscheduler.com/)), but they seems to be a bit overkill for what I need..

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but my feeling is there are a lot of unnecessary screenshots and himhawing around here...what's the punchline?

Comment: You might be right about that. The punchline is: How to check if "this" timestamp is in between the `start` and `stop` fields in the table.

Comment: Lets start with the names of the tables, sample data and expected results

Comment: `WHERE (date_field BETWEEN stop AND start)` doesn't work? those might be keywords, so whatever the fields are really called

Comment: `WHERE start >= ? AND stop <= ?` is the right approach, but your angle brackets are facing the wrong direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
WHERE start >= ? AND stop <= ?
```

to this:

```
WHERE start <= ? AND stop >= ?
```

Comment: will it work if the start date time value is not in table?